# Parallelism in the client or web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, async-await, foreach, parallel-processing

Maybe you can help me here. It's more about understanding.

I have a web service that I can call up with http://localhost:port/person/200. (200 is the ID of the person).
When I execute this in a browser, I get back an XML that is also displayed. The XML consists of about 30 elements.

I have an application in which I call the URL with HTTPClient and get the XML as an object. Now my idea is, since I recently need to retrieve 1000 or more people, to execute the call in parallel. So far it has only been a few people and I have retrieved the URL with the different IDs one after the other.

```
foreach (var personId in Class.NameOfTheListWithIDs.Chunk(50))
{
    await CallAMethod(personId, httpClient);
}
```

For the parallelism I have a Foreach loop in which I run through a list (with .Chunk(50)) and use async/await.

What dangers / problems can there be here if I do it in the application as with the Foreach loop? I have noticed a problem, but I don't want to mention it yet, as I am interested in your answers and don't want to get ahead of myself.

Is it common to create the WebService in such a way that parallelism is also used there? In other words, when I fetch the data from the database for the ID, do you insert an async/await or Task.RUN or something similar at this point? Or do I not need one for the web service, as the application regulates this with the parallelism? Does everything remain synchronised with the web service?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you have power over the web service to add a bulk-get endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to update your webservice to accept requests for multiple persons at a time. Each request will have some amount of overhead, this applies to both the webserver and the database. So you typically want to minimize the amount of requests. You want this to be translated to SQL that looks something like `SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id IN( id1, id2, ... )`

The posted example is asynchronous, but not parallel/concurrent. Each call to `CallAMethod` will execute in after the previous has completed its task.

You can make multiple requests concurrently, but the scaling will be highly dependent on the resources available. It is perfectly possible for throughput to decrease at some level of parallelism. If you want to make calls in parallel you might want to use something like [Parallel.ForeachAsync](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/parallelforeachasync-in-net-6) since this should provide a convenient way to limit the amount of parallelism.

Webservers typically processes requests independently and concurrently, and uses the database for synchronization. There is no automatic 'synchronization' between the client and server, it just passes messages back and forth. If you want to ensure the client has the most recent data you need to build some kind of system for this.

Answer (score -1):

Your example is not parallel at all. Because of the `await`, your code is actually executing `CallAMethod` synchronized, one after the other.

Parallelization using `Task.Run` and `Task.WhenAll`:

```cs
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
var concurrentTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (int number in numbers)
{
  Task concurrentTask = Task.Run(() => DoJobAsync(number));
  concurrentTasks.Add(concurrentTask);
}

await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
```

Parallelization using `Parallel.ForEachAsync` (.NET 6 and later):

```cs
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(numbers, DoJobAsync);

private Task DoJobAsync(int number, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{}
```

Using `Parallel.ForEach` (as a third option) when the job is returning a `Task` (is awaitable) is not recommended as the result is not awaited.
`Parallel.ForEach` itself is not awaitable and will therefore block the current thread.

Your question is really too broad to give you a satisfying answer.
In general, a web service can use parallelism, of course. If it makes sense depends on the use case.